# ViewDeck removes navigation bar when setting center controller

Tags: ios, viewdeck, iiviewdeckcontroller

I am currently using ViewDeck with Storyboards, and have the following setup in the `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
//View Deck Setup
UIStoryboard* mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
UIViewController* menuController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideMenu"];
UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;

self.viewDeckController = [[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:navigationController leftViewController:menuController rightViewController:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewDeckController;
```

However, when I am setting a new `CenterController` from my MenuViewController, the navigation bar is removed, even if loading the same center view controller as I was previously looking at.

```
- (IBAction)viewUsers:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIStoryboard* mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
    UIViewController* viewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"middleViewController"];

    [self.viewDeckController setCenterController:viewController];
    [self.viewDeckController closeLeftView];
}
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Did you solve this situation?, I have the same issue...

Comment: @Camacho I still haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Please, find out the solution in my Answer. I hope this answer solves this situation in your projects!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is remove any "deck constructor" class between AppDelegate and you TabBar. When you need to set or change Deck structure I create a several methods for each one structure. For example, if you want Deck has "leftView" view controller in left side, "rightView" in the right and "tabBarHome" in center, create a method like this in App Delegate:

```
-(void) lanzarHome{
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
IIViewDeckController* deckController =[[IIViewDeckController alloc] initWithCenterViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarHome"]
                                                                    leftViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftView"]
                                                                    rightViewController:[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightView"]];

deckController.leftSize = 100;
self.window.rootViewController = deckController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

}

Now, you must call this method from your viewController with sentence like this:

`[((VKAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) lanzarHome];`

The most important think is that create the method that changes or inits Deck structure from AppDelegate and never you have another class or viewController between delegate and center TabBar.

I hope this answer solve your issue. For me was a very hard work to find out this issue.